# Why does inserting a value into a HashMap always result in the value being None?

Tags: types, rust, hashmap

I am trying to create a `Cacher` struct which will store calculated values in a `HashMap`. The `calculation` method will take one variable of type `T`, do calculations and return a value with the same type `T`. The type for this `calculation` callback will be `Fn(T) -> T`.

I figured out that value which will be a key of `HashMap` has to implement the `Eq` and `Hash` traits. It looked like everything should be working and I could compile my program without errors.

Then I wrote one test to check everything works as expected:

```rust
use std::{hash::Hash, collections::HashMap};

struct Cacher<T, U>
where
    T: Fn(U) -> U,
{
    calculation: T,
    values: HashMap<U, U>,
}

impl<T, U> Cacher<T, U>
where
    T: Fn(U) -> U,
    U: Eq + Hash + Clone,
{
    fn new(calculation: T) -> Cacher<T, U> {
        return Cacher {
            calculation,
            values: HashMap::new(),
        };
    }

    fn value(&mut self, arg: U) -> U {
        let result = self.values.get(&arg);
        return match result {
            Some(v) => v.clone(),
            None => self
                .values
                .insert(arg.clone(), (self.calculation)(arg.clone()))
                .unwrap_or_else(|| {
                    panic!("Unexpected error occurred");
                })
                .clone(),
        };
    }
}

#[test]
fn call_with_different_values() {
    let mut c = Cacher::new(|a: i32| a);
    let v1 = c.value(1);
    let v2 = c.value(2);
    assert_eq!(v2, 2);
}
```

```
thread 'call_with_different_values' panicked at 'Unexpected error occurred', src/lib.rs:31:21
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

When I insert a new value into my `HashMap`, it always finishes with `Option::None`, my `unwrap_or_else` callback is called, and then I throw an error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: BTW idiomatic way to do `.unwrap_or_else(|| panic!("Unexpected error occurred");)`  is `.expect("Unexpected error occurred")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error comes from the fact that `insert` returns an `Option` with the previous value at the key, not the new one. Instead, use [`Entry`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html#method.or_insert):

```rust
fn value(&mut self, arg: U) -> U {
    // ugly workaround to borrow checker complaining when writing these inline
    let value_ref = &mut self.values;
    let calculation_ref = &self.calculation;
    let result = value_ref.get(&arg);
    self.values.entry(arg.clone())
        .or_insert_with(|| (calculation_ref)(arg.clone()))
        .clone()
}
```

Comment: Ok now I see *`If the map did not have this key present, None is returned.`* If I do not have  this value in my map it will always return `None` as you mentioned in your answer.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you recommend me any resource where I can read how to fix this kind of issues with `self` used in lambda? Currently, I am reading [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-01-closures.html)

Comment: The Rust Book (what you're currently reading) is probably the best source for learning Rust. You can also try reading [*Rust by Example*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/).

Comment: So I should back to [`Understanding Ownership`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-00-understanding-ownership.html) and read this chapter one more time. Thank you for your advice